# Connect Firebase with express app.js or routers

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I want to connect my app.js file with index.js file or firebase, Because all of my routes and required files are stored on app.js.

Is there any way to achieve this ?

My code looks something like this

index.js (firebase)

```
var app = require('../app');
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

---

app.js

```
var app = express();
var test = require('./routes/test')
app.use('/test', test)
```

and router test will contain all required code.

---

Folder structure is something like

```
my_project/functions/index.js
my_project/app.js
my_project/routes/test.js
```

I am able to install firebase (firebase init) and hit node apis from index.js file of Firebase. But I want to call my node apis from app.js with the help of index.js of Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you already have your routes in one `./routes` folder which is great. If you're looking for organized simplicity, I would suggest moving your `app.js` file inside your routes folder ( I always call this file `index.js` but that's up to you ). In this case, your routes folder should look something like this:

```
./routes/
|- index.js
|
|- route1.js
|- route2.js
|- route3.js
```

The sole purpose of `index.js` would be to call `app.use()` for each of your routes.

```js
// ./routes/index.js

module.exports = app => {
  app.use('/test', require('./test'));
  app.use('/users', require('./users'))
  app.use('/bookings', require('./bookings'));
}
```

As you can see, `./routes/index.js` sole purpose is to export a function that receives an `app` object that would call `app.use()` for each of its routes.

Subsequently, you can then write your firebase `index.js` like such and call the `./routes/index.js` function:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

require('./routes')(app);

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```